# canvas fillStyle in interval with transparent/opacity

Tags: javascript, canvas, opacity

This small code clear old canvas data in interval:

```
// start interval
ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.width, ctx.height);
ctx.restore();
//some draw code for new graph
...
//end interval
```

My work area become black, because I set black as fill color (`rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)`), but I need a transparent background, not black.

I tried use `globalAlpha` and `imagePutData` but I failed.

How I can do this?

Comment: if I clear rect, it clear all old data, but i need save old data and set opacity for it (that why i use rgba color model, ) until the interval made it completely transparent

Comment: maybe set `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'` and then draw ?

Comment: Thanks! I tryed with globalCompositeOperation to, but not with this value.

Answer (score 26):

I think this will resolve your issue

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)";
```

Answer (score 8):

Using an `rgba(0,0,0,.2)` fillStyle and `fillRect()` works for me on both chrome and firefox - it paints a semi-transparent black fill.  Check to make sure you're not doing something else that's causing a fully opaque paint of some sort.

Answer (score 3):

try ctx.canvas.width, instead of ctx.width

Answer (score 0):

Has your problem been solved

I encountered this problem while using Windows computer

I used `opacity: .99` solved this problem

Comment: Hi 高启明, please familiarise yourself with [answering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before writing your next one. Enjoy your stay at SO :)